# Cant fix lazy loading on a manytomany relationship on

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a self many to many relationship with a table called cuenta aka Account

Cuenta.java looks like

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Autorizacion", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_cuenta") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_cuenta_autorizada") }
    )
    List<Cuenta> cuentasAutorizadas = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cuentasAutorizadas")
    private List<Cuenta> autorizaciones = new ArrayList<>();
```

So I tried to get accounts that are authorized to access my account and I get
failed to lazy  initialize a collecto of role ec.com.myapp.model.Cuenta.cuentasAutorizadas

I tried to do a join but I dont know what am I missing
This is on my cuentaDao.java

```
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer("Select c from Cuenta c left join c.cuentasAutorizadas left join c.autorizaciones  f WHERE ");
        HashMap<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

But if I try to check anything on cuenta.getCuentasAutorizadas() I get a lazy loading problem.  Should I query directly to the autorizacion table directly???
I usually hanlde this many to many relationships by creating my own table but I decided to give hibernate manytomany a chance.

Comment: Your question lacks detail. What do you mean by "lazy loading problem"? Are you talking about a `LazyInitializationException`? Is the relationship loading eagerly? Is the data not what you expect?

Comment: As I detailed below the first code I get  "failed to lazy initialize a collection of role ec.com.myapp.model.Cuenta.cuentasAutorizadas"

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with "left join **fetch**" in your query ?

```
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer("Select c from Cuenta c left join fetch c.cuentasAutorizadas left join fetch c.autorizaciones  f WHERE ");
        HashMap<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

By default, the JPA @ManyToOne and @OneToOne annotations are fetched EAGERly, while the @OneToMany and @ManyToMany relationships are considered LAZY. That means, when loading your entities, JPA did not load the associations at the other of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany.

With "join **fetch**", JPA also loads all associations. So does he for EAGER.

Another way is to use the property "fetch" in your annotation, but it is not recommended:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Comment: As you can see I did have left join con cuentasAutoriazadas, and the problem is the same for both cuentasAutorizadas and autorizaciones. I rather dont use eager because I am just using that information in certain cases.

Comment: @JuanDiego, I say try with "fetch" after "left join", the result is "left join fetch"